# Разделение split() Pattern в Java. Регулярные выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучал регулярные выражения, столкнулся с проблемой в разделении через метод split():

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class CountWordsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "one two, alpha9 12!done.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\s,.!]");
        String[] splited = pattern.split(str);
        for(int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++){
            System.out.println(splited[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Ожидал получить массив splited[] состоящий из

`one`, `two`, `alpha9`, `12`, `done`

Однако получил:

`one`, `two`,  , `alpha9`, `12`, `done`

Т.е. получил лишний пробел в массиве. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем ошибка

Comment: `Pattern.compile("[\\s,.!]+")` будет чуть лучше. И это не ошибка.

Comment: `[\s,.!]` - выбирает одиночный символ, который используется как разделитель, комментарием выше в выражение содержится квантификатор `+` - означающий один и более символов подходящих шаблону. Т.е. в первом случае `,` и ` `(пробел) идущие подряд - это отдельные разделители, а во втором один.

Answer (score 0):

Если цель – найти все букво-цифровые последовательности в строке, используйте

```java
String text  = "one two, alpha9 12!done.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?U)\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
// => [one, two, alpha9, 12, done]
```

См. [пример использования кода](https://ideone.com/tlbZvu). `(?U)\w+` находит последовательности из одной и более букв, цифр, а также знака нижнего подчёркивания, а также диакритических знаков и ещё некоторых символов (из-за поддержки всей таблицы Юникода, см. `(?U)`)